# Color Cells in Rstudio

Tags: r

I have a dataframe that I've imported from a csv. In a free text section the following was included which caused the cell in Rstudio to highlight Red:

```
<P><FONT style="BACKGROUND-COLOR: #ff0000">SP#12. Notified 7/9. Ending 7/29.</FONT></P>



<P>boa bin 7-24-2014</P>



<P>This is an amendment to ALT252143. We are adding habitable basement square footage to Unit 1. </P>



<P><FONT style="BACKGROUND-COLOR: #ff0000">PAID NOMINAL FEE ONLY</FONT></P>
```

I know that the "BACKGROUND-COLOR: #ff0000"bit is what is causing this but I can't find exactly how to reproduce this. Any ideas? The class of the vector is character. I'm using the preview version of Rstudio, not sure if that will make a difference.

Comment: I've narrowed it down to this: `<P><FONT style="BACKGROUND-COLOR: #ff0000"><P><FONT style="BACKGROUND-COLOR: #ff0000">` which you can place in a vector with surrounded by single quotes.